# Can I use Graph Api to filter files in a SharePoint Folder by createdDateTime?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to filter the files within a Sharepoint folder to find those which have been uploaded in the last 24 hours.

I've found that `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[driveID]/items/[folderID]/children`
does return the files I want to process, but when I try to filter the result with
`$filter=createdDateTime ge [Date]`
I get an "Invalid request" error.

What is weird is that I get an "Incomaptible type" error when I accidentally passed the date as a string. Meaning the filter does recognize the type of the field...?

I've been trying to get all the files via
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[driveID]/items`
and then filtering them using the FolderID. like this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[DriveID]/items?$expand=analytics($expand=allTime)&$filter=parentReference/id eq '[FolderID]' and createdDateTime ge [Date]`
But this gives a "General exception while processing" error with no further details...

Does anyone know if it's possible to filter the files in a Sharepoint folder by date created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering `driveItem` children is limited only to item name. The Graph API calls underlaying OneDrive API and the OneDrive API itself doesn't support filtering by createddatetime.

I'm using [\search\query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint. In the body, you can specify the filter and reduce the searching to specific SharePoint folder

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "created>=2023-07-25 AND path:\"https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>/Shared%20documents\""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Return only documents:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "created>=2023-07-25 AND path:\"https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>/Shared%20documents\" AND isDocument=true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I do notice that this can also return the folder itself if it falls within the parameters. Is there a way to filter out the folder itself?

Comment: @TeunVervers IsDocument=true. Update answer